# Which method ideal to query Cloudant for latest doc having same value for a field and again filter on that result?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, nosql

I am very new to NoSQL. My usecase is related to this.... Many users post messages and we store it in cloudant as different documents

```
    {
    id:random,
    userid:xxx,
    timestamp: 1449216912282,
    msg: "Hi..."
    }
```

I want to find out users who have not posted anything for last 5 days - Additionally I want to know if they have posted anything between last five and 10 days. If they have, then send a reminder mail to user to be active.

Which option would be better - views, search, cloudant query? Assume we will be having 1000s of posts per hour

I though of creating view - map(userid,timestamp) reduce as _stats and get max timestamp of each user. Then iterating through this list - we get users who did not post in last 5 days.
Other option was to use search index, get all userids between required timestamps. Compare both lists in application.

Is there any way to do it in a single query without overloading the application? Would Changing data format or creating appropriate index or view help?

Answer (score 0):

If your data looked like this:

```
{
  "_id": "abcdefghijklmon1234",
  "userid" : "user1",
  "timestamp": 1449739485035,
  "msg": "Hi"
 }
```

You could create a MapReduce view that created an index with a key consisting of `[ 2015, 50, "user1" ]`, where "2015" is the year, "50" is the week number and "user1" is the document's userid. This can be achieved with a Map function like this:

```
function (doc) {

  var getWeek = function(t) {
    var date = new Date(t);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3 - (date.getDay() + 6) % 7);
    var week1 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
    return 1 + Math.round(((date.getTime() - week1.getTime()) / 86400000 - 3 + (week1.getDay() + 6) % 7) / 7);
  };

  if (typeof doc.timestamp == "number") {
    var d = new Date(doc.timestamp);
    var weeknum = getWeek(d.getTime());
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    emit( [ year, weeknum, doc.userid], null);
  }
}
```

with a reduce of "_count". This allows queries such as `?startkey=[2015,49]&endkey=[2015,50]&group_level=3` to get a list of users who DID post last week. The list of users who didn't are the users who don't appear in the above list.

This isn't a solution to your problem in terms of "in the last 5 days", but uses week numbers instead.

Comment: I meant to credit the getWeek function to this blog post http://weeknumber.net/how-to/javascript.

Comment: Thanks Glynn. I used this method of map reduce in many other use cases. But for this particular problem, i couldn't figure out how to get list of users who did not post by using the list of users who posted last week - I think we still have to do this in application and not directly from cloudant... I finally used a 'list' feature of cloudant on top of my earlier view to remove rows with timestamp >5 days...not a great idea but works directly from cloudant.